# Cannot find OutputString Offset in UEFI Assembler Application

Tags: assembly, offset, uefi, fasm

I want to Output a String via UEFI in a EFI Application made by Flat Assembler.
This is my Code

```
format pe64 dll efi
entry efimain

section '.text' code readable executable

efimain:

        sub rsp, 20h
        mov [EfiHandle], rcx
        mov [SystemTable], rdx
        mov [ReturnAddr], rsp

        lea rdx, [_hello]
        mov rcx, [SystemTable]
        mov rcx, [rcx + 60]
        mov rcx, [rcx + 8]
        call rcx

        jmp $


section '.data' data readable writeable
EfiHandle dq 0
SystemTable dq 0
ReturnAddr dq 0
ConOutAddr dq 0
_hello du 'Hello from UEFI'
```

Based on the latest UEFI Spec the SystemTable is handed over in RDX on a x64 Architecture. In addition to that based on the Spec the System Table is described as

```
typedef struct { 
EFI_TABLE_HEADER                  Hdr; 
CHAR16                            *FirmwareVendor;
UINT32                            FirmwareRevision;
EFI_HANDLE                        ConsoleInHandle;
EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_INPUT_PROTOCOL    *ConIn;
EFI_HANDLE                        ConsoleOutHandle;
EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL   *ConOut;
EFI_HANDLE                        StandardErrorHandle;
EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL   *StdErr;
EFI_RUNTIME_SERVICES              *RuntimeServices;
EFI_BOOT_SERVICES                 *BootServices;
UINTN                             NumberOfTableEntries;
EFI_CONFIGURATION_TABLE           *ConfigurationTable;
} EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE;
```

The Table Header is defined as

```
typedef struct {
UINT64      Signature;
UINT32      Revision;
UINT32      HeaderSize;
UINT32      CRC32;
UINT32      Reserved;
} EFI_TABLE_HEADER;
```

**EFI_HANDLE** is defined as VOID *, assuming they mean a 8 byte pointer on a x64 arch.

I know it would be simpler to create strucs but I want to do the math directly to go to the correct offset. Based on my calculations to get the ConOut Pointer I go from the SystemTable Offset + 60 (Header + other parts of the SystemTable). Then the OutPutString methods is in the Ouput Protocol, defined as:

```
typedef struct _EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL {
EFI_TEXT_RESET           Reset;
EFI_TEXT_STRING         OutputString;
EFI_TEXT_TEST_STRING     TestString;
EFI_TEXT_QUERY_MODE          QueryMode;
EFI_TEXT_SET_MODE            SetMode;
EFI_TEXT_SET_ATTRIBUTE       SetAttribute;
EFI_TEXT_CLEAR_SCREEN        ClearScreen;
EFI_TEXT_SET_CURSOR_POSITION SetCursorPosition;
EFI_TEXT_ENABLE_CURSOR       EnableCursor;
SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_MODE      *Mode;
} EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL;
```

So after moving the offset of the Output Protocol via `mov rcx, [rcx + 60]` I need to jump to the OutputString which I want to call, so I need to skip 8 bytes again `mov rcx, [rcx + 8]`.

As I am not familiar with Assembler a lot I am pretty sure the issue must be in locating the correct OffSet of the OutputString method, but I cant spot it.

Comment: The offsets seem ok. But isn't `OutputString` a **method**? I.e., looking at its signature, doesn't it need a `EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL` pointer as its first parameter? What happens if you use `mov rax, [rcx+8] / call rax` in the last two lines?

Answer (score 3):

Margaret pointed me to the solution:

1. Yes I missed the parameter passing part, First Param is a Pointer to the Output Protocol (so this must be in RCX) and the second value is the String in RDX. So moving the pointer to OutputString in rax does work
2. The Offset is still incorrect. I just read the Spec again and it says

> Unless otherwise specified all data types are naturally aligned.
> Structures are aligned on boundaries equal to the largest internal
> datum of the structure and internal data are implicitly padded to
> achieve natural alignment.

With that the size of the FirmwareRevision which is an UINT32 is actually also 8 bytes (padded) in memory. So the Offset to ConOut would be 0x40 (or 64 bytes).

With those changes I finally get my String printed out to the screen.

Comment: Well done and kudos for self answering. This is indeed a useful QA :)